# Manipulating the legend for a Seaborn Jointplot

Tags: matplotlib, seaborn, visualization, legend

I am seeking advice on how to edit the colors of the symbols in my legend when using a seaborn jointplot with several other matplotlib scatterplot layers.

*My Specific Question:*

> Given the data and the current chart below, how can make an adjustment to the code so that the colors of the latter five points on the legend (e.g., "3", "4", "5", "6", "8") can be changed to gray (i.e., #b9b9bd)?

The reproducible code has been pasted below, but there is a publicly accessible [Colab Notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/12L04YrwrvHrYkkO9V8FPOOd1O0DaNlfr?usp=sharing) that can be copied and used for experimentation.

Reproducible Example

```
# import pacakges

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# load the mpg dataset
mpg_df = sns.load_dataset("mpg")

mpg_df = (
    mpg_df
    .astype({"cylinders":"category"})
)

mpg_df["cylinders"] = (
    mpg_df["cylinders"]
    .cat
    .as_ordered()
)

# establish the markers
_markers_cylinders = {
    3:"P", 
    4:"d", 
    5:"v", 
    6:"X",
    8:"s"
}

# establish colors for countries
_palette_origin = {
    "usa":"#fca847",
    "japan":"#8aed7b",
    "europe":"#7b81ed"
}

kws={
  "s": 225,
  "linewidth": 2
}

# plot the jointplot -- establish the figure -- the content of the plot is not needed just the marginal ditributions
jp = sns.jointplot(
    data=mpg_df,
    x="weight",
    y="mpg",
    hue="origin",
    palette=_palette_origin,
    markers=",",
    marginal_kws={"fill":True},
    color="w",
    height=10,
    s=1
)

# plot scatter by origin and cylinder as layers on the original jointplot
origin = ["usa", "japan", "europe"]

for nation in origin:
  df = mpg_df[mpg_df["origin"] == nation]
  for k,v in _markers_cylinders.items():
    jp.ax_joint.scatter(
        data=df[df["cylinders"]==k],
        x="weight", 
        y="mpg", 
        marker=_markers_cylinders[k], 
        c=_palette_origin[nation],
        edgecolor="k",
        alpha=0.6,
        **kws
    )

jp.ax_joint.grid(
    color="k",
    linestyle=":", 
    linewidth=0.75
)

han, lab = jp.ax_joint.get_legend_handles_labels()

lab = [
    "USA",
    "Japan",
    "Europe",
    "3", 
    "4", 
    "5", 
    "6", 
    "8"
]

jp.ax_joint.legend(
    han[0:8],
    lab[0:8],
    title="Origin & Cylinders",
    fontsize=15,
    bbox_to_anchor=(1.20, 1),
    title_fontsize = 14,
    markerscale=2.5,
    shadow = True
)
sns.move_legend(
    jp.ax_joint,
    loc="upper left",
    bbox_to_anchor=(1.20, 1),
    markerscale=0.25
)
plt.show()

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Do you mean that you want the marker color of the scatterplot and the color of the symbol in the legend to be different colors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be accomplished by reusing the existing handles and then changing the face color of the marker.

```
han, lab = jp.ax_joint.get_legend_handles_labels()

new_han = [
    handles[0],
    handles[1],
    handles[2],
    Line2D([0], [0], marker='P', markerfacecolor='#b9b9bd', markeredgecolor='black', markersize=14, ls=''),
    Line2D([0], [1], marker='d', markerfacecolor='#b9b9bd', markeredgecolor='black', markersize=14, ls=''),
    Line2D([0], [2], marker='v', markerfacecolor='#b9b9bd', markeredgecolor='black', markersize=14, ls=''),
    Line2D([0], [3], marker='X', markerfacecolor='#b9b9bd', markeredgecolor='black', markersize=14, ls=''),
    Line2D([0], [4], marker='s', markerfacecolor='#b9b9bd', markeredgecolor='black', markersize=14, ls='')
]

jp.ax_joint.legend(
    new_han,#han[0:8],
    lab[0:8],
    title="Origin & Cylinders",
    fontsize=15,
    bbox_to_anchor=(1.20, 1),
    title_fontsize = 14,
    markerscale=2.5,
    shadow = True
)
```

[image]

Comment: I used the addition of `new_han` you recommended, and it removed the orange color for the symbols but the gray color is missing. In other words, there is just a whitespace next t the numeric labels in the legend. The updated notebook shows how I implemented your code: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/12L04YrwrvHrYkkO9V8FPOOd1O0DaNlfr?usp=sharing

Comment: The version of seaborn in the Colab environment is out of date and has been brought up to date. Still the same situation, so now I brought matplotlib up to date. The result was improved and I could draw the same graph as the answer.

Comment: After executing `!pip install seaborn==0.12.0` and `pip install matplotlib==3.6.0`, I was able to duplicate your results within the Colab notebook.